# Редирект на страницу без расширения на чистом PHP

Tags: php

Привет всем! Наверное я много людей уже достал такими вопросами, но все же.

Написал небольшой код, который по идее должен заменять стандартный редирект `.htaccess` на страницу без расширения. Вот код:

```php
if(stristr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php")){
    $currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $shortCut = str_replace(".php", "", $currentPage);
    header("Location:".$shortCut);
}
```

Но после этого я словил ошибку `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Помогите улучшить этот код.

PS. В `.htaccess` стоит параметр `Options +MultiViews`

Comment: Что в шурткат и от куда редирект

Comment: @Naumov Она получает значение строки `$currentPage` и убирает из него расширение. А редирект сам на себя только без расширения.

Comment: Извините, я немного дебил, так как я поставил SCRIPT_NAME а не REQUEST_URI.

Comment: А зачем делать такую небезопасную и нагрузочную вещь, если вы все равно используете .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получался очень смешной вопрос, и на него не менее смешной ответ. Реально надо было заменить `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` на `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Вот так:

`if(stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php")){
    $currentPage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $shortCut = str_replace(".php", "", $currentPage);
    header("Location:".$shortCut);
}`